# Failed to execute goal maven release:prepare

Tags: maven

I'm having problems when I run mvn release:prepare. I have the following message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-release-plugin: 2.5.1: prepare (default-cli) on project marketplace-po
c: Failed to invoke Maven build. Error configuring command-line. Reason: Maven executable not found at: C: \ dev \ apache-maven-3.3.1 \
bin \ mvn.bat -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: It looks like you Maven installation is not correct which means your mvn binary is not in your path.

Comment: My maven everything is working, only the plugin release that is not working. In my path there mvn.bat only mvn.cmd

Comment: Please accept the answer on your question. The answer from Lucas is the real solution, not some dirty workaround.

Answer (score 109):

As of version `3.3.X`, Maven renamed `mvn.bat` to `mvn.cmd`.  This is fixed in the `maven-release-plugin` version `2.5.2`: [MRELEASE-902](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-902)

They suggest adding the following section in case the fixed plugin version is not picked up automatically:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: While the 'copy mvn.cmd to mvn.bat' was my first idea as well and will most probably work, this is in fact a little cleaner.

Comment: Fixed in 2.5.2, or 2.5.1?

Comment: @Wuaner, it says in the answer: _This is fixed in the maven-release-plugin version 2.5.2_

Comment: I see... have to specify the version of maven-invoker to 2.2 if release plugin version is under 2.5.2, as ur codes illustrated.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: I copied mvn.cmd -> mvn.bat and have maven verison 3.5.4 but still it causing the issue.
Tried this maven-invoker solution and it worked! ta

Answer (score 32):

I just had same problem when running from eclipse, it resolved by making
 `copy of mvn.cmd to mvn.bat`

And it worked for me.

Comment: This is a workaround, but it will work. The more correct solution is what Lucas suggests.

Comment: WORKED FOR ME ON MAC

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too at using Maven 3.3.1 in Windows 8.1. I searched on it and found that `mvn.bat` moved to `mvn.cmd`. Still, I don't know how to solve it at the version. So, I downloaded Maven 3.2.5 and there was the **`mvn.bat`** file. And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, i had same problem with maven 3.5.0 instalation, so just copy mvn.cmd and rename it to mvn.bat at C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin.

Comment: ‐1. You did the exact same thing as three other answers on this question.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas sorry, ignore my answer

Comment: @Rahulk Do you know you can delete your answer?

Comment: Guillaume Georges- it doesn't harm anyone i think. Enjoy