# Maven executable not found

Tags: maven

Having to do some work with Maven I came across an error message:

```
"Maven exception: Error configuring command-line. Reason: Maven executable not found at: ...\bin\mvn.bat"
```

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about your environment and what you're trying to do?

Comment: Did you install Maven? And if so, where? You could also try to set MAVEN_HOME..., and add %MAVEN_HOME%\bin to your PATH (Guess you are on Windows, trying to find mvn.bat :))

Comment: Yes Maven is installed.I can see from command prompt "mvn -version" gives:Apache Maven 3.3.3 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2015-04-22T21:51:42+08:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache\maven
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

Comment: I am trying to install SYNCOPE and then facing this problem

Answer (score 24):

It seems things have changed in maven 3.3.3, I had the same issue on windows. Looking in the maven bin directory there is no longer a mvn.bat file, but there is a mvn.cmd file. I copied mvn.cmd to mvn.bat and things progressed...

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is a workaround that will only fix the issue on your local machine. The real solution is to upgrade the maven release plugin version to > 2.5.2 You can also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755620/failed-to-execute-goal-maven-releaseprepare

Answer (score 2):

Ensure to

> Add the unpacked distribution’s bin directory to your user PATH
>   environment variable

like explained in the [Maven Install Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/install.html).

Comment: I followed this process when maven was installed and still ran into the issue raised above. Work around for windows is to do as @theINtoy suggests.